# A direct limit of pullbacks

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let an $R$-module $C$ be a direct limit of finitely presented $R$-modules $C_i$, and we have a short exact sequence as follows:

$$0→A↪B\stackrel{\pi}→C→0.\qquad (S)$$

From each $C_i$ to the direct limit $C$ we have a homomorphism $γ_i$ which we suppose that could be lifted to a homomorphism $λ_i:C_i→B$. Let $B_i=\{(x,y)∈B⊕C_i : π(x)=γ_i(y)\}$ be the pullback of $π$ and $γ_i$.  The rule $ρ_i(y)=(λ_i(y),y)$ for $y$ in $C_i$ defines a splitting from $C_i$ to $B_i$ for $π_i: B_i→C_i$. Now we get split s.e.s.:

$$0→A→B_i\stackrel{\pi_i}→C_i→0.\qquad (S_i)$$

My question is how  could one prove that $B$ is the direct limit of $B_i$? If so, $(S)$ would be the direct limit of the sequences $(S_i)$.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Comment: "$(S)$ would be the direct limit of the sequences $(S_i)$" is a claim or a question?

Comment: @user26857:Sorry! When the identity map from $A$ to $A$, and the projections from $B_i$ to $B$ were rendered, they, along with $γ_i$, make $S$ the direct limit of the direct system of $S_i$. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

For every $i$ we have $C_i=B_i/A$. Taking direct limit, when $B'$ denotes the limit of $(B_i)$, we get $$C=B'/A,$$ and $B'$ is a submodule of $B$. But we know that $C=B/A$, hence $B'=B$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but why $B'$ is a submodule of $B$?

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but if the $B_i$'s are not inside $B$, then where do all the maps $A\to B_i$ come from? All we have concerning $A$ is a map to $B$.